# Date module: detect if an end date was set

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a content type with a date field. It is setup to collect an end date (optional). The field type is Date (UNIX timestamp).

The field is to store "experience" as (from) January 2011 - (to) March 2012.

If I don't check the "show end date" when creating content, the end date is the same than the start date. But in my case, I sometimes need to collect an end date that would be the same than the start date (January 2011 - January 2011).

**So how do I know if that "show end date" checkbox was checked?**

Right now here is what I get when the end date is the same than the start date:

```
value (String, 10 characters ) 1443650400
value2 (String, 10 characters ) 1443650400
```

And this is what I get when the "show end date" was not checked:

```
value (String, 10 characters ) 1443650400
value2 (String, 10 characters ) 1443650400
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess and assume you have the end-date defaulting to the start-date in the Date field, field-settings?

[image]

That way if they click the checkbox for **Show End Date**, they have to provide a value for it. otherwise it will be empty; essentially letting you know if the checkbox was checked or not.

Comment: That sounded like a good catch and it was set on "Same as start date". So I changed it to "No default value" but the same still happens. Btw, the field is used in a field collection. Don't know if this can make any difference but it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed with using it in a field collection: whenever I tick that "Show end date" option for a field, then save my node, it will go back to that option not being checked - but still, an end date is saved. Strange!

Comment: Make sure to update the node you are testing, happens to me sometimes. 
I'll look more into it this morning. If by default the value is staying the same regardless of the action then maybe, the checkbox just allows the user to edit the value, and that is a default value set, which means you might have to hook into something. Alternatively you can give two date fields one for start and end, that way the end will always be empty if nothing is provided. You do loose some out-of-box functionality like showing the date from start to finish on calendar module, ect, nothing too crucial.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the different entries from the node, updated the field settings, then added new entries.

Comment: I think it's acceptable to check if  `value1 == value2` to determine if it's not been checked.

If the start date is literally the same as end date then whats the point of the end date data? it's useless.

 If there is a `Start Date = 10/05/15 - 3:40:55PM`  and a `End Date = 10/05/15 - 3:40:55PM` Then I can assume the user didn't select an end date.

  If the values are different (same day different time) then you know the person selected a end date. If they clicked the box then chose nothing, that's a user entry issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me. For this content type, dates are saved as [month/year]. So if I was to store a start date of `October 2015` and an end date of `October 2015` then both dates would be the same. And then I have no way to tell if an end date was saved or not.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. With Month + year  format, and user provides a value you get the same result as if they didn't so that should be pretty obvious you need something else to differentiate.

 Add day of week or time to it. `Oct 2015` to `Oct 2015` is pretty useless information even if the user provided that value. `Oct 1 2015` to `Oct 31 2015` is useful.  then when a user has a start date and end date the same then you can assume its one date. If `startdate == enddate` It means its only one Day, in your case one month.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. But the use case is: users can add their professional experience and education, like you would do in your linkedin profile. So a position is from month/year to month/year, title, description. So it could happen that you want to add a training session you had, from July 2015 to July 2015. We don't want to have exact dates. So in this case, I have no way to tell if it was from July 2015 to July 2015 or from July 2015 to now (= current). If an end date was not provided and that I can find that out, then it would be obvious it is a current position.

Comment: Well the checkbox you are trying to get i'm pretty sure is saved in the `field_config` table but it only saves whether or not the checkbox was checked when the field was created, I dont think theres a way to get that value of show end date, because there no DB data for that. 
 you can use JS and AJAX if you want.but you cannot put the value `Current` into a field that is saving as a date format. Have you thought about making multiple select lists? one for month, one for year? or just a checkbox that says `Currently work here`? if checked dont use the end-date value and use the value `Current`?

Comment: I don't think it is saved in field_config table. At least I can't find it. I think the checkbox appears checked when the end date is different from the first date. Why do I think that? Edit a node, check the "show end date", enter the same date as the start date, save the node, edit it again, the checkbox is unchecked. Anyway, I ended up doing 2 separate date fileds "start" and "end" and a checkbox "current" and that's it. But that still feels like a strange behavior to me.

Comment: Because that's the default functionality, if the dates are the same then the end date is irrelevant; it makes sense. You need to add more granularity to it in order for the module to output two dates. You're not going to get the results you are looking for with the default Date field. I would have a boolean indicating IF they still work at that job, then render the output accordingly if they clicked it.